# Material Button not showing in android

Tags: android

I am using the Material button in android. When I am using the OutlinedButton style the button is not showing at all. I even tried to change the color of the text and stroke color but nothing seems to work.

When I use any other style than OutlinedButton(eg. TextButton) it works.

```
               <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
                android:id="@+id/btn_resend_otp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Resend OTP"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                app:strokeColor="@color/black"
                />
```

Comment: Is it working without adding ``style=....`` ?

Comment: which version of material components are you using?

Comment: com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03

Comment: Yes, It's a problem in *v1.2.0-alpha03*. I have checked with *v1.0.0*, it works there. Even it works in *v1.2.0-alpha02*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably it's a bug of **v1.2.0-alpha03**. Try downgrading the version to **1.2.0-alpha02**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'
```